# Using SSH ProxyJump and SSH Agent Forwarding back to back

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, port-forwarding

There is a series of `ProxyJump`s I have to do, to get to a specific target system `T`. The last hop to `T` does NOT support TCP forwarding at all, causing `ProxyJump` and `ProxyCommand` to fail, so that's not an option.

`Me --> Bastion A --> Bastion B --> T`

I'm looking for an SSH config, that allows me to execute `ssh T` on my machine and be connected to `T`. As mentioned above, `Bastion B` does NOT allow for agent forwarding.

I already did some attempts with `RemoteCommand` to execute `ssh -A T` automatically and also adding the `-tt` option to force SSH to attach STDIN/STDOUT of the `B<->T` connection to the original `Me <-> Bastion B` connection, but that effectively disabled a lot of terminal functionality (i.e. tab-completion, etc.), because `RemoteCommand` is a non-interactive shell.

**Is there a way to "macro" this behavior using my own SSH config file?**
As Bastion B is also the target sometimes, I cannot simply auto-connect using .bashrc or something, that pseudo-forwards me every time I connect.

> A possible solution - I just thought of this as I'm typing - would be to push an environment variable like `MY_NEXT_HOP=T` via SSH and evaluate that in `.bashrc`, triggering `ssh -A T`, if it's set. This way, it's launched in an interactive shell and I don't lose shell functionality. **However, is there a better solution I am missing?**

**Edit:** To clear up some confusion, see my SSH config file and the output of my connection attempt below:

```
# .ssh/config
Host BastionA
    User myUserA
    HostName BastionA.domain.com
    IdentityFile "ssh.key"

Host BastionB
    User myUserB
    HostName BastionB.domain.com
    ProxyCommand ssh.exe -W %h:%p BastionA
    IdentityFile "ssh.key"
    ForwardAgent yes   # if this is necessary

Host T
    User myUserB
    HostName T.domain.com
    ProxyCommand ssh.exe -W %h:%p BastionB
    IdentityFile "ssh.key"
```

This is what I'm getting on a connection attempt `ssh T`

```
warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
# Bastion A reached successfully
warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
# Bastion B reached successfully
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

At the same time, doing `ssh BastionB` works perfectly fine and I get my shell. So I think that this last hop fails, which is the `ProxyCommand` to `T`.

As you can tell by `ssh.exe` in the config, I'm doing this from a Windows host, however it's still OpenSSH, so it shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Can you clarify what stops you from using ProxyCommand?

Comment: Your description of the limitations on B are confusing me, because `ProxyJump` and `ProxyCommand` are independent of both TCP forwarding and agent forwarding. Can you clarify the exact limitations and situation on B?

Comment: Check my answer to this UL SE Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406695/how-to-ssh-forwarding-with-allowtcpforwarding-set-to-no . So what tools are available on bastionB? Being able to *not* use a tty would be a bonus not a drawback

Comment: I added some extra information to clarify question.
@user1686 It's apparently "administratively prohibited", so the SSH config doesn't allow it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Is that the case? I thought they were both utilizing a plain TCP tunnel to forward the connection to the next host.

Comment: @A.B Nice answer, thanks! Unfortunately, neither socat nor netcat are available on Bastion B. I'll check out the alternatives and see what they can do.

Comment: @GxTruth nor the bash shell and the cat command? I'd be surprised

Comment: @A.B Bash and cat are there. I'll see if that one works in my setup.

Comment: @GxTruth: The _specific command_ that you were using, `ssh -W`, uses a TCP tunnel. Other commands (like the suggested nc or socat) don't, they just run the command on the server.